# How to log-in in C# Windows Forms (getting data from MySQL Server/Database)?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, authentication, passwords

I want to ask how can I implement a login functionality in a Windows Form provided that I have two fields username and password. In the database I have a table called `users` and in it 2 fields - username and password. I want to get the password from the database, then compare it to the one entered in the textbox field and if the passwords are the same I want to open /show/ a new form. However, I get always in the `catch` block of the code. I would like to ask why is that?

```
try
{
    if (i == 2)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    conn.Open();
    string query = "select password from users where username = @usr and password = @pas";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pas", password);

    MySqlDataReader myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    string rez = (string)myreader.ToString();

    if (rez == password.Text)
    {
        frmMain mainF = new frmMain();
        mainF.Show();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect!");
    i++;
}
```

Comment: what have you got under ex object? What is description on exception?

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the code it looks like you're passing a textbox as your password parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pas", password);
```

Then later you do this check:

```
if (rez == password.Text)
```

This suggests that `password` is a textbox.

So the correct code should be:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pas", password.Text);
```

I'm also going to assume that `username` is a textbox so when you create the username parameter you should use:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", username.Text);
```

Answer (score -1):

If the textbox id is "username" and "password", then you need to pass that textbox's value like below :

"username.text" and "password.text"

Then you will be able to login.

Answer (score -1):

You're doing it wrong. You need to read from the reader. Here's what you should do:

```
  try
  {
    if (i == 2)
    {
      Application.Exit();
    }

    conn.Open();
  string query = "select password from users where username = @usr and password = @pas";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pas", password);

    MySqlDataReader myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    var password = string.Empty;
    while(myreader.Read())
    {
     password = myreader["password"];
    }


     if (password.Equals(password.Text))
     {
      frmMain mainF = new frmMain();
      mainF.Show();
     }
     else
     {
       MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect!");
       i++;
     }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   MessageBox.Show("An error has occured while reading from the database!");

   }
```